# How to parse the formatted string that contains pipe and bracket in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Javascript, I have the following String:

`"|John Doe|[user:001] created article |Article Name|[article:001]"`

How do I make the code parse it to `"<a href="/user/001">John Doe</a> created article <a href="/article/001">Article Name</a>"`?

**My Solved Problem Code**

based on suggestions from Agi Hammerthief

```
var splitedStr = str.split("|");
var filtered = splitedStr.filter(function (el) {
    return el !== "";
});

$.each(filtered, function( index, value ) {
    var mySubString = value.substr(
        value.lastIndexOf("[") + 1,
        value.lastIndexOf("]") - 1
    );
    if (mySubString.trim()) {
        filtered[index] = value.replace('['+mySubString+']', '');
        var infoLink = mySubString.split(":");
        filtered[index - 1] = "<a href='/"+infoLink[0]+"/"+infoLink[1]+"'>" + filtered[index - 1] + "</a>";
    }
});

console.log(filtered.join(""));
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question you have provided is too broad as currently written.  Try to [edit] the question to add more detail, specifically what you've tried so far and what hasn't worked.  We are here to help fix errors in code, not create code from scratch.

Comment: I am sorry, i will update more detail later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line *almost* looks like a fragment from a [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) document (although it doesn't use the same format for hyperlinks). If you're creating the String instead of getting it from an outside source, you might want to change the format and use a markdown processor.

Alternately:

1. Split the String on "|" (pipe)
2. Filter out empty Strings in the array
3. Use a loop to find the content between "[" and "]" (`indexOf()` and `substring()`) and make a link with text from the previous item in the array.

Comment: thank you for providing a solution, like I understand using an alternative method.
but I will also try using markdown processor

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regex** and groups:

`\|([\w ]*)\|\[([\w:]*)\]([\w ]*)\|([\w ]*)\|\[([\w:]*)\]`

Group 1 is 'John Doe', 2 is 'user:001', 3 is ' created article ', 4 is 'Article Name', 5 is 'article:001'

Comment: thank you for providing a solution, but i will try using markdown processor